# Ethereum Presale Wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, wallets, presale

I have the json file and the password. Is Go Ethereum the only option for import and updating the wallet?

I am no programmer. I jump on board with Ethereum because it is, I believe, the only way forward to peaceably change the social and economic paradigm.  I started with S1 Ant Miners, played NXT, and then believed in the change Vatalik purposed.

I need some guidance and/or instruction, even if it is "You are going to have to figure this out on your own, start here."

There are similar questions BUT the other answer options, with the exception of GEth, are out of date.

Comment: This is the first answer I have seen that mentions pyethsaletool.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your wallet.json file you will see the following values:

```
{
  "encseed": "97...d4",
  "bkp": "d7...b3",
  "ethaddr": "df...e7",
  "btcaddr": "1b...hM",
  "email": "redacted@gmail.com"
}
```

You can check this repo https://github.com/ethereum/pyethsaletool and look at the genesis_block.json file. If your "ethaddr" from above isn't in there, you have no pre-sale ETH to claim.

If it IS in that file, recover your ethereum address private key using the script from that repo like so:

```
python pyethsaletool.py -w "wallet.json" getethprivkey
```

With this private key, you can now import it into Metamask and continue on with your wealthy life!

Comment: Thanks, on to Python and Github.

Comment: Good luck, hope you find the ETH!